# 'bea' is not defined?

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
def money():
    cashin = input("Please insert money: £1 Per Play!")
    dif = 1 - cashin
    if cashin < 1.0:
        print ("You have inserted £", cashin, " you must insert another £", math.fabs(dif))
    elif cashin > 1.0:
        print ("Please take your change: £", math.fabs(dif))
    else:
        print ("You have inserted £1")
    menu()

def menu():
    print ("Please choose an ARTIST: <enter character ID>")
    print ("<BEA> - The Beatles")
    print ("<MIC> - Michael Jackson")
    print ("<BOB> - Bob Marley")
    cid = input()
    if cid.upper == ("BEA"):
        correct = input("You have selected the Beatles, is this correct? [Y/N]:")
        if correct.upper() == ("Y"):
            bea1()
        else:
            menu()
    elif cid.upper() == ("MIC"):
        correct = input("You have selected Michael Jackson, is this correct? [Y/N]:")
        if correct.upper() == ("Y"):
            mic1()
        else:
            menu()
    elif cid.upper() == ("BOB"):
        correct = input("You have selected Bob Marley, is this correct? [Y/N]:")
        if correct.upper() == ("Y"):
            bob1()
        else:
            menu()
    else:
        print ("That is an invalid character ID")
        menu()
```

this is part of my code for a jukebox

my code is giving me the error that bea is not defined if I type 'bea' on the 'CHOOSE AN ARTIST' input. but i'm not trying to use it as a function or a variable? I want to use an if statement to decide what to do based on the users input

usually this works for me, I don't know what the problem is. This is only a section of my code, if you need to see more let me know

Comment: You call `bea1()`, where is this defined?

Comment: @Cyber As well as `mic1()` and `bob1()`

Comment: @Martijn: That seems like a mildly bad canonical duplicate, since it's tagged [python-3.x] (the real problem is that the OP incorrectly thinks they're using 3.x--I wonder if there's a better real duplicate that doesn't make this mistake that would make a better target. Unfortunately, most of the potential ones I've come across are already closed as dupes of that one :( )

Comment: @Wooble: Yeah, its not the best perhaps. If you have a better one, lets promote that one and dupe vote the rest. I went on a spree recently and only later realised I had picked the 3.x post as the canonical.

Comment: @Wooble: still, better to find a dupe quickly then to let in the rush of answers to this *tired out* dupe.

Comment: @Wooble: How about this one: [Problem running a Python program, error: Name 's' is not defined](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2790565). Reopen that one, vote to close others as a dupe of that one. The list is at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/2612948

Answer (score 4):

In Python 2.x, to get a string from a prompt, you use [`raw_input()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) instead of [`input()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input):

```
cid = raw_input()
```

The `input` function in Python 2 is not equivalent to `input` in Python 3. It does not return a string, but **evaluates** it. In your case, you type `bea` and it tries to evalueate `bea` as an expression. But this name is not defined.

As mentioned in the docs for `input`:

> Equivalent to `eval(raw_input(prompt))`.

Also, as @frostnational notes in his comment, you forgot to actually call the `upper` method on the next line, so you are trying to compare the method itself with a string. You want

```
if cid.upper() == "BEA":
```

Comment: Also replace `cid.upper == "BEA"` with `cid.upper() == "BEA"`

Comment: Probably should mention `input()` is `eval(raw_input)`  *Edit: you already did :P*